# cups issue printing to remote raw queue with Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing, brother

I have a Brother FAX-2820 that is set up as a raw queue on a Raspberry Pi that is serving as a print server.  Since the Brother supplied driver doesn't support non-Intel platforms I had to use the raw queue on the RPi.

So I install the driver on the client machines (Linux and Windoze) and set the printer to be the raw queue on the RPi print server.

From Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using the Brother driver / PPD I am able to print perfectly to the raw queue on the RPi.  But on Ubuntu 14.04 (and probably newer) installations the printer just spews out blank pages.  No error messages, and nothing of interest that I have found in the logs yet.

From Windows I can print to the FAX-2820 via the raw queue on the RPi using Samba so that is working fine.  And the 12.04 machine still prints just fine.

Also I tried connecting the FAX-2820 directly to the Ubuntu 14.04 system via USB and it prints fine in that configuration.  So it is only printing to the remote raw queue from 14.04 that appears to be problematic.

The RPi print server is set to allow printing by anyone.

Has anyone seen this type of problem and if so how did you resolve it?  Any suggestions on where to look in the chain from the 14.04 installation to the remote print server?

My guess is that for some reason the CUPS configuration on the 14.04 system isn't sending the properly processed print data via the PPD to the RPi print server.

Thanks,
Burt